# How to disable line wrapping in Spacemacs?

Tags: customization, spacemacs

I have limited emacs experience. Tried to find a solution to disable line wrapping in [Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs) but couldn't find any.

The solution to this problem in Vim is to execute `set nowrap`. But it's not working in Spacemacs.

Any solution to this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've never seen Spacemacs before, but it sounds like you're looking to disable [`auto-fill-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoFillMode).  Try `M-x auto-fill-mode` (which will toggle it on and off) and, if that works and is what you mean, you can disable it automatically in your init file.

Comment: Try the following `C-h v` `truncate-lines` after starting Spacemacs.  This will tell you what it is set to when starting up.

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin Thanks your tip helped me debug the issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add this to your `~/.spacemacs` config function:

```
(add-hook 'hack-local-variables-hook (lambda () (setq truncate-lines t)))
```

Comment: I respectfully disagree with this answer, because it is essentially trumping (overriding) previous settings (if any contradict) and it works in this instance because the `hack-local-variables-hook` is called later in time in the loading process of a buffer.  The better solution would be to make it major-mode specific, or design a better global solution that does not use the `hack-local-variables-hook`.

Comment: @lawlist I agree it's a hack but AFAIK there is no mode for truncate lines. If you want it globally it can be tricky via major mode hooks, and it won't be better than this. It may be better to use the toggle function instead but it does not offer to force activation of truncate lines.

Answer (score 34):

On November 23 [syl20bnr](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3756/3972) added a new toggle called `spacemacs/toggle-truncate-lines`, available on <kbd>SPC t l</kbd>. Another toggle you may also find useful is `spacemacs/toggle-visual-line-navigation`, available on <kbd>SPC t L</kbd>. See [Github commit](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/commit/99fdb754d1f5727af1be8e50ff81732a4c318bdd).

This is how your `dotspacemacs/user-config` can look like to enable both toggles:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  "Configuration function for user code.
This function is called at the very end of Spacemacs initialization after
layers configuration. You are free to put any user code."
  (spacemacs/toggle-truncate-lines-on)
  ;; Visual line navigation for textual modes
  (add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'spacemacs/toggle-visual-line-navigation-on)
)
```

If you don't know where `dotspacemacs/user-config` is, it's in your `.spacemacs` file, available by pressing <kbd>SPC f e d</kbd>.

The [hook](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html) for `spacemacs/toggle-visual-line-navigation-on` is because it doesn't work globally otherwise.

Comment: I've been looking for that mode hook for ages!  Thanks!

Comment: This is the equivalent of `:set nowrap`. Thanks!

Comment: `SPC t L` for the easy win.

Answer (score 9):

`M-x toggle-truncate-lines RET` is the Emacs equivalent of Vim's `:set wrap!`

Comment: And programmatically: `(setq truncate-lines t)`

Comment: @nanny Thanks, you suggestion works for disable line wrapping after starting spacemacs. But @lawlist suggestion of adding `(setq truncate-lines t)` to ~/.spacemacs not working.

Comment: @Vamsee -- That line of code that I suggested is meant to be used *programmatically* -- e.g., when writing a function.  It can be used on demand by typing:  `M-x eval-expression RET (setq truncate-lines t) RET`

Comment: @lawlist  I actually wrote it inside the function `dotspacemacs/config` which is inside file ~/.spacemacs. This file is executed after spacemacs is loaded. I can say this file is loading since my theme settings, font customisations are working.

Comment: @Vamsee -- `truncate-lines` is a buffer-local variable, which means that the code needs to be executed while focus is inside the target buffer.  The library you cited is a collection of a million and one preselected user customizations, including certain selections based on various major modes.  To really track down your issue, you would need to specify what major mode you are using -- then it would be necessary to check all the major mode hooks used by the library in question, and even then, its possible you have that setting somewhere else.  For example, `visual-line-mode` enables wrapping

Comment: @lawlist  Finally it's working I had to set custom variable inside the function `custom-set-variables` and not in `dotspacemacs/config` function. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I added this to my init file inside `dotspacemacs/user-config` to disable automatic line breaking:

```
(spacemacs/toggle-auto-fill-mode-off)
```

By default, you can toggle on/off with `SPC t F`.

Answer (score 1):

I would have commented, but I don't have enough reputation, so I will just write it here.

Mirzhan Irkegulov's first expression worked, but the second one didn't work
`(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'spacemacs/toggle-visual-line-navigation-on)`

Instead, I had to use `(global-visual-mode t)`

Comment: did you put (global-visual-mode t) in the .spacemacs file? In the user-config section?

Answer (score 0):

### Simplified Configuration

After experimenting with the above solutions, I found only this works for me, specifically for `spacemacs`. By inserting the following code into the `spacemacs/user-config` section, line truncation was effectively enforced:

```lisp
;; -------------------------------------------------------------
;;               Enable Line Truncation
;; -------------------------------------------------------------
(setq-default truncate-lines t)
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'spacemacs/toggle-truncate-lines-on)
```